# Present a sheet from a menu item

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I have a Cocoa app that calls a sheet from the main window. This works fine from an NSButton on the main window. However, when I call from a MainMenu item, the sheet shows as a separate window. Is this expected behavior, or just expected from me :) I have studied [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978615/cocoa-osx-call-a-sheet-from-a-menu-item) ..

I call the sheet with this code:

```
-(IBAction) showSettingsSheet:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    settingsSheetController = [[SettingsSheetController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"SettingsSheet"];
    [settingsSheetController beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSUInteger returnCode) {

        if (returnCode == kSettingsSheetReturnedOk) {
            NSLog(@"Settings Returned ok");

        } else if (returnCode == kSettingsSheetReturnedCancel) {
            NSLog(@"Settings Returned cancel");
        } else {
            //self.categoryDisplayString = @"Oops!";
            NSLog(@" Ooops");
        }

    }];

}
```

UPDATE

This is how the Attributes Inspector is set:

[image]

Comment: Please follow the updated ans below and make it correct if really it helps

Comment: oops. i forgot.. fixed. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, if you want to display sheet in a mainmenu then try the below steps:-

[image]

Uncheck the visible at launch option inside attribute inspector of window which you want to display as a sheet attached the screenshot as well

Comment: Hi Hussain, thanks for responding. That setting is unchecked.. I will update my question with the attribute settings..

Comment: Follow this link   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html